# Loading additional audio for IE 8

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am having trouble getting IE 8 to play audio files consistently using Media Element. IE 8 will play the first audio file, but does not play the next one. It works fine in all other browsers.

```
  function playAudio(audioId) {

        var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#' + audioId + '', {
            autoplay: true,
            pauseOtherPlayers: true,
            success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {

                mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
                    //stuff 
                }, false);
            }
        }
        );
        player.load();//is this necessary?
        player.play();

    }
    <p onclick="playAudio('Audio01')">Play 1</p>
    <p onclick="playAudio('Audio02')">Play 2</p>
    <p onclick="playAudio('Audio03')">Play 3</p>

    <div style="display:hidden;">
    <audio id="Audio01">
        <source src="a01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

    <audio id="Audio02">
        <source src="a02.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

    <audio id="Audio03">
        <source src="a03.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
  </div>
```

IE 8 does not consistently play the additional audio clips. There are no errors thrown. Is there something else I need to do to get IE to work the same as everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it would seem IE 8 does not support

```
 trigger('pause')
```

Also, it has trouble with player.play()

This is what I ended up if it helps someone else:

```
    function playAudio(audioId) {

        new MediaElement(audioId, {

            pauseOtherPlayers: true,
            success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {

                // call the play method
                mediaElement.play();

            }
        });
    }
```

Then I managed a local variable to toggle if it was playing, so that IE 8 would not overlap audio files.